# Overlayfs: 'Special device overlay doesn't exist'

Tags: linux, filesystems, overlayfs

I'm trying to use the `overlay` filesystem driver, and it's giving me an error:

```
$ sudo mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/mnt/ccs-overlayfs-lower,upperdir=/mnt/ccs-overlayfs/upper,workdir=/mnt/ccs/overlayfs-work /mnt/ccs
mount: special device overlay does not exist
```

Every bit of documentation I've seen uses the device `overlay`, so why am I having problems?

Answer (score 51):

The error message is actually a red herring. Check the spelling of your `lowerdir`, `upperdir`, and `workdir` paths. If there is any mistake, the `overlay` driver will give you that nonsense about the device not existing, where instead it should be saying "hey, your lowerdir doesn't exist!" or something.

I found this solution on the Arch Linux forums: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1599436#p1599436

Comment: I guess sometimes more info can be found in `dmesg`. At least if one of the `lowerdir` folders is missing.

Comment: Mount commands are really good at lying.